# Menu loop Python doesn't work

Tags: python, loops, menu

How do I loop the else question on menu ?

So far I have:

```
loop()

selection=raw_input('How Many Apples (limit 3): ')
print ' '
if selection=='1':
    p = a
    print '<1 Apple added to Cart>'
    break
elif selection=='2':
    p = a*2
    print '<2 Apples added too Cart>'
    break
elif selection=='3':
    p = a*3
    print '<3 Apples added too Cart>'
    break
else:
    print '[try again]'
```

I want to loop the else option back to the top so if people choose a option not on the list it will ask again!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there

```
while True:
    selection=raw_input('How Many Apples (limit 3): ')
    print ' '
    if selection=='1':
        p = a
        print '<1 Apple added to Cart>'
        break
    elif selection=='2':
        p = a*2
        print '<2 Apples added too Cart>'
        break
    elif selection=='3':
        p = a*3
        print '<3 Apples added too Cart>'
        break
    else:
        print '[try again]'
```